# How to determine problem location for "Could not determine recommended JdbcType for 'PersonBO'"?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm porting an application from Payara & EclipseLink to Quarkus (using Hibernate). Hibernate throws a

```
JdbcTypeRecommendationException
    Failed to start quarkus: io.quarkus.dev.appstate.ApplicationStartException: 
org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.spi.JdbcTypeRecommendationException: 
Could not determine recommended JdbcType for `Entity`
```

This was running fine with EclipseLink. I've read all related issues on Stack Overflow. I have already added the Hibernate specific annotation `@JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)` to all properties which have a JSONB column in the PostgreSQL database. [This issue][1] suggests that the error is not in the entity class itself, but in any reference. There are really many references!

I would like to know if I can make Hibernate to tell me which class and which property is throwing the exception?

Hibernate forced me to add the annotation `@DiscriminatorValue(value = "P")` to `PersonBO` which is neither required by EclipseLink nor by JPA 2.2. Maybe the problem is related to this?

This is the entity (I left out all setters and getter for Java basic types)

```java
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
@Table(name = PersonBO.TABLENAME)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.CHAR, name = "prssubclass")
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "P")
public class PersonBO {

    /** Name of this database table is {@value} */
    final public static String TABLENAME = "person";

    // --- Database columns
    private UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
    private List<AddressGeoBO> adrGeos = null;
    private Map<String, Object> prsAttributes = null;
    private Gender prsGender = null;
    private Set<UUID> tags = null;

    @Convert(converter = UuidConverter4jpa.class)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    @Id
    public UUID getId() { return id; }

    @Json
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            mappedBy = AddressGeoBO.FIELD_PERSONBO,
            targetEntity = AddressGeoBO.class, orphanRemoval = true)
    public List<AddressGeoBO> getAdrGeos() { return adrGeos; }

    @Convert(converter = JsonMapConverter4jpa.class)
    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)
    @Json
    public Map<String, Object> getPrsAttributes() { return this.prsAttributes; }

    @Convert(converter = Gender.Converter4jpa.class)
    @Json(converter = Gender.Converter4json.class)
    public Gender getPrsGender() { return this.prsGender; }

    @Convert(converter = JsonSetUuidConverter4jpa.class)
    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)
    @Json
    public Set<UUID> getTags() { return tags; }
}
```

The many to one referenced table looks like:

```java
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
@Table(name = AddressGeoBO.TABLENAME)
public class AddressGeoBO {
    final public static String TABLENAME = "addressgeo";
    private UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
    private PersonBO personBO = null;

    @JoinColumn(name = "personId", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = PersonBO.class)
    public PersonBO getPersonBO() { return this.personBO; }
}
```

Subclass of `PersonBO`:

```java
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
@Table(name = "identity")
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "I")
public class IdentityBO extends PersonBO { ... }
```

Full Stacktrace when runing `mvn build quarkus:dev`:

```
    2023-09-24 15:40:20,279 ERROR [io.qua.dep.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain] (main) Failed to start quarkus: io.quarkus.dev.appstate.ApplicationStartException: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.spi.JdbcTypeRecommendationException: Could not determine recommended JdbcType for `com.djarjo.person.PersonBO`
        at io.quarkus.dev.appstate.ApplicationStateNotification.waitForApplicationStart(ApplicationStateNotification.java:58)
        at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.StartupActionImpl.runMainClass(StartupActionImpl.java:123)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.firstStart(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:113)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:423)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:55)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInCl(CuratedApplication.java:138)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInAugmentClassLoader(CuratedApplication.java:93)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.start(DevModeMain.java:131)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.main(DevModeMain.java:62)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.spi.JdbcTypeRecommendationException: Could not determine recommended JdbcType for `com.djarjo.person.PersonBO`
        at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.spi.UnknownBasicJavaType.getRecommendedJdbcType(UnknownBasicJavaType.java:37)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.internal.InferredBasicValueResolver.from(InferredBasicValueResolver.java:222)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue.buildResolution(BasicValue.java:480)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue.resolve(BasicValue.java:310)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue.resolve(BasicValue.java:300)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.lambda$processValueResolvers$4(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1842)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.removeIf(ArrayList.java:1682)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.removeIf(ArrayList.java:1660)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processValueResolvers(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1841)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1827)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:328)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.boot.FastBootMetadataBuilder.build(FastBootMetadataBuilder.java:406)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.PersistenceUnitsHolder.createMetadata(PersistenceUnitsHolder.java:101)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.PersistenceUnitsHolder.constructMetadataAdvance(PersistenceUnitsHolder.java:73)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.PersistenceUnitsHolder.initializeJpa(PersistenceUnitsHolder.java:40)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.HibernateOrmRecorder$1.created(HibernateOrmRecorder.java:78)
        at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.ArcRecorder.initBeanContainer(ArcRecorder.java:79)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ArcProcessor$generateResources844392269.deploy_0(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ArcProcessor$generateResources844392269.deploy(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:70)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:44)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:124)
        at io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.StartupActionImpl$1.run(StartupActionImpl.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73312803/could-not-determine-recommended-jdbctype-for-class
```

Comment: Can you show us the entity involved in the exception?

Comment: I have replaced "entity" with "PersonBO" in the title and have added the full stack trace. My primary question was "I would like to know if I can make Hibernate to tell me which class and which property is throwing the exception?" which I have highlighted in bold. The markup has been removed by you. So please suggest how this question can be properly asked on stacktrace!

Answer (score 0):

A month later I solved the single issue mentioned as an example to explain the question. I went the hard way to remove ALL entities and reinserted them one by one to locate the Hibernate problem which was on another entity as in the example. This other entity both had a reference to the entity "Person" and its primary key. This leads to above error message. It took me many hours to locate the root cause due to misleading exception message.

All in all this a lesson for writers of libraries like Hibernate:

Whenever throwing an exception contain the data which leads to the problem!