# Java Spring Boot: Getting error "Could not determine recommended JdbcType for <class>

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

We are trying to run a Spring Boot Java application that contains these three models:

```
@Entity (name = "chatbox")
public class Chatbox {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "chatbox")
private List<SentPrompt> conversationHistory;

public Chatbox() {
    this.conversationHistory = new ArrayList<>();
}
//Getters and Setters`
```

The chatbox model:

```
`@Entity(name = "employees")
public class Employee {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

//can be null
@Column(name = "email")
private String email;

//can be null
@Column(name = "manager")
private String manager;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"employee"})
private List<SentPrompt> sentPrompts;

public Employee() {}

public Employee(String name, String email, String manager) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.manager = manager;
    this.sentPrompts = new ArrayList<>();
}`
```

and the SentPrompts model which joins the models above:

```
`@Entity
@Table(name = "prompts")
public class SentPrompt {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="employee_id")
private Employee employee;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="chatbox_id")
private Chatbox chatbox;

@Column (name = "question")
private String question;

@Column (name = "response")
private String response;

public SentPrompt(){}

public SentPrompt(String question, String response) {
    this.question = question;
    this.response = response;
}
```

`

When trying to run the application we get this error:
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Could not determine recommended JdbcType for `com.valuedbnta.demo.Models.SentPrompt`

We have tried changing Java versions and looking at the dependencies in pom.xml however we cant find an issue.  We've also looked at other similar questions and they haven't helped us yet either.

Any insight into this error would be great, thank you!

Comment: It looks quite similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73312803/could-not-determine-recommended-jdbctype-for-class. 
Try reviewing your relationship definitions.

Comment: Can you also share how pom is currently configured?