# Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Could not determine recommended JdbcType for Java type <class>

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

Experiencing error while running my application.

Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Could not determine recommended JdbcType for Java type <class>

Here is my error log :

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=51012:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\User\Desktop\evrdayDocs\WorkEarly\Projects\SpringBootProjects\fleet-app\target\classes;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\3.2.2\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\3.2.2\spring-boot-starter-aop-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.21\aspectjweaver-1.9.21.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\3.2.2\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\5.0.1\HikariCP-5.0.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\6.1.3\spring-jdbc-6.1.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\orm\hibernate-core\6.4.1.Final\hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\jakarta\persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\3.1.0\jakarta.persistence-api-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\jakarta\transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\2.0.1\jakarta.transaction-api-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.5.3.Final\jboss-logging-3.5.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\6.0.6.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-6.0.6.Final.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\io\smallrye\jandex\3.1.2\jandex-3.1.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.6.0\classmate-1.6.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.14.11\byte-buddy-1.14.11.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\4.0.4\jaxb-runtime-4.0.4.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-core\4.0.4\jaxb-core-4.0.4.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\angus\angus-activation\2.0.1\angus-activation-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\4.0.4\txw2-4.0.4.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\4.1.2\istack-commons-runtime-4.1.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\jakarta\inject\jakarta.inject-api\2.0.1\jakarta.inject-api-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\antlr\antlr4-runtime\4.13.0\antlr4-runtime-4.13.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\3.2.2\spring-data-jpa-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\3.2.2\spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\6.1.3\spring-orm-6.1.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\6.1.3\spring-context-6.1.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\6.1.3\spring-tx-6.1.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\6.1.3\spring-beans-6.1.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\2.1.1\jakarta.annotation-api-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\6.1.3\spring-aspects-6.1.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-security\3.2.2\spring-boot-starter-security-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\3.2.2\spring-boot-starter-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\3.2.2\spring-boot-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\3.2.2\spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\3.2.2\spring-boot-starter-logging-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.4.14\logback-classic-1.4.14.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.4.14\logback-core-1.4.14.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.21.1\log4j-to-slf4j-2.21.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.21.1\log4j-api-2.21.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\2.0.11\jul-to-slf4j-2.0.11.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\2.2\snakeyaml-2.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\6.1.3\spring-aop-6.1.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-config\6.2.1\spring-security-config-6.2.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-web\6.2.1\spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\6.1.3\spring-expression-6.1.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf\3.2.2\spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\thymeleaf-spring6\3.1.2.RELEASE\thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\thymeleaf\3.1.2.RELEASE\thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\attoparser\attoparser\2.0.7.RELEASE\attoparser-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\unbescape\unbescape\1.1.6.RELEASE\unbescape-1.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\3.2.2\spring-boot-starter-web-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\3.2.2\spring-boot-starter-json-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.15.3\jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.15.3\jackson-annotations-2.15.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.15.3\jackson-core-2.15.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.15.3\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.15.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.15.3\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.15.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.15.3\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.15.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\3.2.2\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\10.1.18\tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\10.1.18\tomcat-embed-el-10.1.18.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\10.1.18\tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.18.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\6.1.3\spring-web-6.1.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\io\micrometer\micrometer-observation\1.12.2\micrometer-observation-1.12.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\io\micrometer\micrometer-commons\1.12.2\micrometer-commons-1.12.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\6.1.3\spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\extras\thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6\3.1.2.RELEASE\thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\2.0.11\slf4j-api-2.0.11.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\mysql\mysql-connector-j\8.3.0\mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.18.30\lombok-1.18.30.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\4.0.1\jakarta.xml.bind-api-4.0.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\jakarta\activation\jakarta.activation-api\2.1.2\jakarta.activation-api-2.1.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\6.1.3\spring-core-6.1.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\6.1.3\spring-jcl-6.1.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-core\6.2.1\spring-security-core-6.2.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-crypto\6.2.1\spring-security-crypto-6.2.1.jar com.spirosvatikiotis.fleetapp.FleetAppApplication

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.2.2)

2024-02-17T00:07:24.041+02:00  INFO 9264 --- [           main] c.s.fleetapp.FleetAppApplication         : Starting FleetAppApplication using Java 17.0.6 with PID 9264 (C:\Users\User\Desktop\evrdayDocs\WorkEarly\Projects\SpringBootProjects\fleet-app\target\classes started by User in C:\Users\User\Desktop\evrdayDocs\WorkEarly\Projects\SpringBootProjects\fleet-app)
2024-02-17T00:07:24.043+02:00  INFO 9264 --- [           main] c.s.fleetapp.FleetAppApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-02-17T00:07:24.588+02:00  INFO 9264 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-02-17T00:07:24.609+02:00  INFO 9264 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 14 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2024-02-17T00:07:25.041+02:00  INFO 9264 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
2024-02-17T00:07:25.050+02:00  INFO 9264 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-02-17T00:07:25.050+02:00  INFO 9264 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.18]
2024-02-17T00:07:25.102+02:00  INFO 9264 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-02-17T00:07:25.102+02:00  INFO 9264 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1017 ms
2024-02-17T00:07:25.270+02:00  INFO 9264 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2024-02-17T00:07:25.336+02:00  INFO 9264 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.4.1.Final
2024-02-17T00:07:25.372+02:00  INFO 9264 --- [           main] o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
2024-02-17T00:07:25.549+02:00  INFO 9264 --- [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2024-02-17T00:07:25.568+02:00  INFO 9264 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-02-17T00:07:25.777+02:00  INFO 9264 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@6fef75c6
2024-02-17T00:07:25.779+02:00  INFO 9264 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2024-02-17T00:07:26.105+02:00 ERROR 9264 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Could not determine recommended JdbcType for Java type 'com.spirosvatikiotis.fleetapp.models.Country'
2024-02-17T00:07:26.105+02:00  WARN 9264 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Could not determine recommended JdbcType for Java type 'com.spirosvatikiotis.fleetapp.models.Country'
2024-02-17T00:07:26.105+02:00  INFO 9264 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2024-02-17T00:07:26.118+02:00  INFO 9264 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2024-02-17T00:07:26.120+02:00  INFO 9264 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-02-17T00:07:26.129+02:00  INFO 9264 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-02-17T00:07:26.145+02:00 ERROR 9264 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Could not determine recommended JdbcType for Java type 'com.spirosvatikiotis.fleetapp.models.Country'
```

Here is the Country.java file :

```
package com.spirosvatikiotis.fleetapp.models;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Country {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String code;
    private String capital;
    private String description;
    private String nationality;
    private String continent;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "country")
    private List<State> states;

}
```

The classes that are related to Country.java are the following :

Client.java :

```
package com.spirosvatikiotis.fleetapp.models;


import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Client {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String city;
    private String phone;
    private String website;
    private String email;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name= "countryid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Country country;
    private Integer countryid;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "stateid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private State state;
    private Integer stateid;

    private String details;
}
```

Location.java :

```
package com.spirosvatikiotis.fleetapp.models;


import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Location {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;

    private String description;
    private String details;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="countryid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Country country;
    private Integer countryid;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="stateid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private State state;
    private Integer stateid;

    private String city;
    private String address;
}
```

Person.java :

```
package com.spirosvatikiotis.fleetapp.models;


import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

import java.util.Date;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@MappedSuperclass
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String othername;
    private String title;
    private String initials;
    private String gender;
    private String maritalStatus;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="countryid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Country country;
    private Integer countryid;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="stateid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private State state;
    private Integer stateid;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date dateOfBirth;
    private String city;
    private String address;
    private String phone;
    private String mobile;
    private String email;
    private String photo;

}
```

State.java :

```
package com.spirosvatikiotis.fleetapp.models;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class State {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String capital;
    private String code;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "countryid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Country country;
    private Integer countryid;
    private String details;
}
```

Supplier.java :

```
package com.spirosvatikiotis.fleetapp.models;


import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Supplier {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String city;
    private String phone;
    private String mobile;
    private String webesite;
    private String email;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name= "countryid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Country country;
    private Country countryid;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name= "stateid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private State state;
    private State stateid;

    private String details;
}
```

Im i looking at the right error spot or this is having to do with something else like versions or dependencies?

Comment: I think this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73312803/could-not-determine-recommended-jdbctype-for-class

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help mate. That was the first article i dumbed into when started searching for a possible solution. Thank you tho

Comment: can you please test without the joinColumn of country in the Supplier.java class  ?

Comment: "Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Could not determine recommended JdbcType for Java type 'com.spirosvatikiotis.fleetapp.models.Country' again..

Comment: try changing     private Country countryid;
 to private Integer countryid;
also      private State stateid; to private Integer stateid;

Comment: I did as u said .  Private Integer countryid  && private Integer stateid;  my app is running. thank u my friend. now i have to investigate the error and if my code is functional for the project as a whole!!!  thank u

Comment: i am adding the answer  so you can accept it as a working  answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changes to be made in Supplier.java :

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name= "countryid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Country country;
private Integer countryid;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name= "stateid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private State state;
private Integer stateid;

private String details;
```